# Insert high quality image to MS excel web

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

After adding image to excel web, the image resolution is reduced. How do I add image without reducing image resolution?

Comment: [Turn off picture compression](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658)  Try Google next time. Example [excel+reduces+image+quality](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+reduces+image+quality)

Comment: Insert in Excel for desktop with high fidelity and upload.